# Printing uint8_t variables using std::cout in C++

Tags: c++, cout

In the following code, it appears that `std::cout` does not print the variable of type uint8_t properly.

```
int main() {
    uint8_t var = 16;
    std::cout << "value: " << var << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
value:
```

I don't have problem with similar uintX_t types.

I know I'm missing something here, but I can't figure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

`uint8_t` maps to `unsigned char` on most systems. As the result, the override that interprets `16` as a non-printable character gets invoked. Add a cast to `int` to see the numeric value:

```
std::cout << "value: " << (int)var << std::endl;
```

Comment: I was suspecting that this implicit char casting is going on. But why? doesn't the type name, uint8_t, suggest that it should remain in its int form?

Comment: @narengi `uint8_t` is only a `typedef`, not a built-in primitive type. Because of that the compiler has no way to distinguish an override on the actual primitive type and an override on a `typedef`-ed type: it's the same function to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So if I understood you correctly, it's a typedef on `char`, right?

Comment: Answer to self, and future readers: here is the list of typedefs for uintX_t class of type variables:
`typedef unsigned char  uint8_t;` 
`typedef unsigned int  uint16_t;` 
`typedef unsigned long int  uint32_t;`
`typedef unsigned long long int  uint64_t;`

Comment: @narengi: Which predefined types are used for the `[u]intN_t` types varies from system to system. That's why the the `[u]intN_t` types exist, because the sizes of the predefined types vary. `uint16_t` would be defined as `unsigned int` only if `int` is 16 bits, which is rare for hosted systems.

Comment: @KeithThompson I see your point. But the takeaway message for me was that [u]intX_t type variables are just typedefs, and are defines by various sorts of built-in types, ranging from char to int and long int, etc. and shold not be necessarily treated as integer types. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What happens when I pass "var" into a function? Do I also have to cast it to "(int)," or will the program pass the correct value outside of printing?                    Why does that happen, anyway?

Comment: @Pototo If the function has a single overload that takes an `int`, you do not need a cast. `operator <<` has several overloads, one of which is for `char`.

Comment: Aight. C++ is a crazy languange