# Are int8_t and uint8_t really integers? What are their use?

Tags: c++

What exactly is `uint8_t` made for? If it remains indistinguishable from `unsigned char` and cannot be used to overload functions?

I found many answers in this post : [std::cout deal with uint8_t as a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145753/stdcout-deal-with-uint8-t-as-a-character)

So I've reedited the question entirely and re-titled the question.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: there are countless number of duplicates: [std::cout deal with uint8_t as a character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39145753/995714), [Behavior of cout << hex with uint8 and uint16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23575381/995714), [Printing uint8_t variables using std::cout in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30856861/995714)...

Comment: No, it doesn't. I really think we should be allowed to overload functions on other criteria than the length and sign of types in c++. Compilers could still be smarter.

Comment: The point is that you can't overload a function on different type-*aliases*, you need to have a [different type](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CRcvWAt1q13GDEEs).

Comment: don't edit the question to modify its meaning entirely. Ask another question if you want

Answer (score 4):

On all systems with 8-bit bytes, they are variants of `char`. This includes the type-aliases for e.g. `uint8_t` (which is a type-alias for `unsigned char` on such a system).

And no matter what type-alias you have, `char` (and `unsigned char` and `signed char` (yes those are three distinctive types)) will be treated as *characters* by the stream output operator `<<`.

If you want to print the integer value of any `char` based type you need to cast it to e.g. `int`. As in

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(my_uint8_t_var) << '\n';
```

---

As a side-note: There *are* systems which doesn't have 8-bit bytes. On such systems type-aliases like `uint8_t` are not possible, and does not exist. If you see e.g. [this fixed-width integer reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) you will see that the exact fixed-width integer types are optional.

Comment: I see the purpose of portability. But casting is bothering me, static_cast<unsigned>(my_uint8_t_var)  will resize my variable I suppose and there must be an overhead somewhere when handling bytes of files or vectors

Comment: @Maelstrom Casting will not change the size, type or value of the variable itself, only the result of the cast will be e.g. `unsigned`. You can of course [read](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) or [write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) raw data, but then that will be a bitwise copy and not a translation into the textual representation of the value.

Answer (score 0):

`uint8_t` is an 8 bit unsigned integer. For storing values from 0 to 255. It usually has the same range as an unsigned `char` but is one of several explicitly sized integer types available with `cstdint`